# tax configuration blank after migration (and upgrade) 2.3.2 -> 2.3.3

Tags: configuration, tax, migration, magento2.3.3, white-screen

We migrated from magento-1.9.2.4 to magento-2.3.2 without problems so far.
After upgrading to magento-2.3.3 (using composer) the tax configuration (Sotres -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax) page only shows a white screen.

Therefore we tested to migrate from magento-1.9.2.4 directly to magento-2.3.3 - same outcome.

Sadly there is no error shown in the system.log or any info in the debug.log. No exception.log or reports were created.

We truncated all tax_*-tables - still same outcome.
we remove all %tax% entries from core_config_data table  - still same outcome.

Cache is disabled.

Source code of blank page:

```html
<style>
    .highlighted {
        background-color: #DFF7FF!important;
    }
</style>
<form action="http://10.0.0.12:8000/magento2/2.3.2/382t9egh/admin/system_config/save/key/f9315ea2f5be58a51fd9aa811d3511d684705a4260a366d5c0854759124fdf24/section/tax/" method="post" id="config-edit-form"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="c2Q2qjPKd7aIDSZK" /></div>
    <div class="accordion">

<div class="entry-edit form-inline">
```

That's all we got.
Any idea what causes the problem?
If not: any idea how to investigate or start proper testing?

Comment: I think an issue in vendor/vertex/module-tax/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Comment: Thank you for your hint. 
Disabling the module worked for us. 
Yet we don't know what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using `2.3.3` or less version then you need upgrade vertax module version to

`3.3.0`.

If you using 2.3.4 then no need to **upgrade** vertex version, it is already added.

### If your `2.3.3` or less version

then open composer.json and `"vertex/module-tax": "3.3.0"`.`composer.json` look like:

```
    "require": {
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.3.3",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3",
        "vertex/module-tax": "3.3.0"
    },
```

But you also have to  remove `vertex/product-magento-module` package from .

```
    "require": {
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.3.3",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3",
        "vertex/module-tax": "3.3.0"
    },
"replace": {
    "vertex/product-magento-module": "*"
}
```

After that, you need to run `composer update` command to get the package /module at your system.

**Before do that Please take the backup of code properly. Because of task update `composer.json`.**

Answer (score 1):

I got solution to Tax Configuration Blank Issue after Upgrade to Magento 2.3.3

**Solution 1: Update vertex vendor**

Open vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Extractor/EavAttributeExtractor.php file (edit vendor file is bad practice but temp solution)

Find the below code at line ~121:

> $attribute->setLabel($eavAttribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel());

And replace it with the below code and save the file.

> $attribute->setLabel($eavAttribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel() ?:
>   $eavAttribute->getAttributeCode());

Changing the single line of code above will solve the issue of the tax configuration blank page in Magento 2.3.3.

**Solution 2: Disable Vertex_Tax Module**

Magento dir=>app/etc/config.php

> 'Vertex_Tax' => 1, to 'Vertex_Tax' =>0,

Then run

> php bin/magento s:upgrade

Hope it will be help someone special scenario.

Comment: @ulbiopro late answer hope now get  causes the problem.

Comment: didn't focus on this for a time, since we don't need the vertex module.
I marked updating the module as solution, because to me it is the cleaner way, as they changed the quoted lines in their 3.3.0 version.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm this behaviour.
i have found one post where a typo should be the reason for this
.../vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php

namespace Vertex\Tax\Model\Flexfield\Processor;
namespace Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor;

f to F

but this did NOT help

the good thing is i have learned that disabling this vertex helps us
we dont need
i have disabled many more modules ...